# I can't keep open console in C

Tags: c, visual-studio

I started to learn C and I am using Visual Studio for this. But I can't keep open console when I compile it. I wasn't do anything others program like Dev-C++ or Codeblocks. How can I solve it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
printf("My name is Alex\n");
return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: you add a breakpoint to `return 0;` or you add `getchar();` or start it with CTRL + F5

Answer (score 1):

It is strange that Visual Studio closes the console because it should not do that.
You can explicitly provide a `system("pause");` or `getchar();` code-line at the end but before the `return 0;` line.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getch();` to keep console,like following

```
int main()
{
printf("My name is Alex\n");
getchar();
return 0 ;

}
```

Use code blocks IDE to practice,it will be helped to you,good luck :)

Comment: `getch()` might be acceptable for certain geo-regions that seem to have a bizarre preference toward using the antiquated TurboC for education but it is *not* standard C :-) Please use `getchar()` instead.

Comment: yup,it's true, i really miss that :( thank for your advice and i reedited my code

Answer (score 1):

If you want VS to keep your console window open, you can modify your code to put `getchar()` before `main()` exits, but that will only work if your code actually exits via that method.

Having it crash or call `exit()` or any one of a dozen other ways  that bypasses exiting via `main()` will not work with that method.

In any case, VS itself will do this for you in a much cleaner way. Simply use <kbd>CTRL-F5</kbd> (start without debugging) instead of <kbd>F5</kbd> (start debugging) to run your code.

Doing so will cause VS to output the line:

> Press any key to continue . . .

and await a keystroke before closing the console.